# TFS Checked out files

Tags: team-foundation-server

How do I check all the checked out files from the Visual Studio TFS Server in one go?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the node you are interested in, select **Find in Source Control > Status**

In the dialog box, choose **Display all checked out**.

Comment: Taking this a step further, I recorded a macro of myself doing those steps, and then assigned a keyboard shortcut to it via Tools -> Options.

Comment: "Find in Source Control" doesn't exist out of the box; it requires TFS power tools to be installed for your version of TFS.